# "Warning: Prop `className` did not match..." when use formik-material-ui TextField and material-ui TextField in one component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, formik, formik-material-ui

When I use formik-material-ui TextField and original material-ui TextField (which is bound to Formik with fieldToTextField function) in one component I have a warning

> Prop className did not match. Server: "PrivateNotchedOutline-legendLabelled-11 PrivateNotchedOutline-legendNotched-12" Client: "PrivateNotchedOutline-legendLabelled-7 PrivateNotchedOutline-legendNotched-8".

This warning is shown only if component's `variant` is `outline`.

Here is an example which produces the warning.

```
//Form.jsx
import React from 'react'
import { TextField } from 'formik-material-ui'
import TextFieldFormik from '../TextFieldFormik.jsx'
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik'

export default function MyForm(props) {
  return (
    <Formik
      enableReinitialize
      initialValues={{ first: 'first', second: 'second' }}
      onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        console.log(values)
      }}
    >
      {({ submitForm, isSubmitting, errors, touched, values }) => {
        return (
          <Form>
            <Field
              component={TextField} //This is a formik-material-ui TextField
              name="first"
              variant="outlined"
              fullWidth
              label="first"
            />

            <Field
              component={TextFieldFormik} //This is a material-ui text field bound to Formik with fieldToTextField function
              name="second"
              variant="outlined"
              fullWidth
              label="second"
            />
          </Form>
        )
      }}
    </Formik>
  )
}
```

```
//TextFieldFormik.jsx
import React from 'react'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'
import { fieldToTextField } from 'formik-material-ui'

export default function TextFieldFormik(props) {
  return <TextField {...fieldToTextField(props)} />
}
```

My configuration:

- "next": "^11.1.0",
- "react": "^17.0.2",
- "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
- "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
- "formik": "^2.2.9",
- "formik-material-ui": "^4.0.0-alpha.1"

Answer (score 1):

Changing `import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'` to `import {TextField} from '@material-ui/core'` in the `TextFieldFormik.jsx` file fixed the issue.